# How to change bottomsheet corner radius? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
.presentationDetents([.fraction(   1), .height(400), .medium, .large])
```

using .cornerRadius(INT) does not work here, there seems to be no way to set a corner radius.

Comment: Hi, I don't think this is possible unless you create your own bottom view. As it's an inbuilt overlay synonymous to all apps that use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to change the corner radius of a sheet in SwiftUI until iOS 16.4. iOS 16.4 adds a `presentationCornerRadius:` modifier: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/presentationcornerradius(_:)

The iOS 16.4 SDKs are included in Xcode 14.3.

This is the sample code copied from Apple's documentation on the new modifier:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showSettings = false

    var body: some View {
        Button("View Settings") {
            showSettings = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSettings) {
            SettingsView()
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                .presentationCornerRadius(21)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to support older versions of iOS, there are fully or partially custom solutions for you

Popular packages that do not overuse the native modal dialogs implementation:

- [AndreaMiotto/PartialSheet](https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/PartialSheet)
- [lucaszischka/BottomSheet](https://github.com/lucaszischka/BottomSheet)
- [weitieda/bottom-sheet](https://github.com/weitieda/bottom-sheet)

This package was written by me and uses Apple's private API and allows you to customize native modal dialogs:
[NativePartialSheet](https://github.com/CoolONEOfficial/NativePartialSheet)